# FreeBSD - problem with linking protobuf

Tags: freebsd, make, linker, gnu-make

I have a small application that was tested on Linux and it worked. Now I would like to build the same code on FreeBSD. To build it on FreeBSD I needed to change a little my Makefile. Here is my amended version:

```
CXX := gcc
LDFLAGS += -L/usr/local/lib -R/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -R/usr/lib -L/usr/local/include -R/usr/local/include -L/usr/include -R/usr/include
CXXFLAGS += -pedantic -Wall -Wextra  -std=c++17 
LIBS += -lprotobuf -lstdc++
INCL += -I/usr/local/include

SRCS := my_app.cpp \
        file1.pb.cc \
        file2.pb.cc 
                
OBJS := $(SRCS:% = %.o)
target := my_app

all:
    $(CXX) $(OBJS) -o $(target) $(LIBS) $(INCL) $(LDFLAGS)

%.o:%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCL) $(LDFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf *o $(target)
```

The problem is that I get a lot of linker errors. All of them are related to google protobuf functions. I am including one of them below:

```
/usr/local/bin/ld: /tmp//ccpo2Qek.o: in function `main':
my_app.cpp:(.text+0x3a4): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::MessageLite::SerializeAsString[abi:cxx11]() const'
```

To build the application I use gmake. I have installed protobuf on my FreeBSD system using `pkg install`. I can find some google protobuf .h files in `/usr/local/include` and some protobuf .so libraries in `/usr/local/lib`. I tried to add these locations to `LDFLAGS` but it still doesn't work.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: It is a bit strange that you use C compiler to build C++ code and link to `libstdc++` manually.

Comment: And why not use the base clang?

Comment: Yes, it is a bit strange. I found this hint on the Internet. On Linux I used g++ but it didn't work on FreeBSD. Now I use c++ and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced gcc with c++ and now it works.